# how do i change the color of typeface on photoshop?

Tags: color, typography

[image]i used masking + Gaussian blur + curves on my typeface on photoshop

after all, i wanted to change the color of typeface by

clicking the letters using magic wand,

but the shape of letter is changed as i filled colors on it.
(the typeface becomes thicker)

how can i change the color of typeface?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm understand your problem correctly, but I'd simply right click on the layer, then choose `Blending Options --> Color Overlay --> (choose the color you want)` and it will change the color.

Then, just repeat for each layer (you can simply `copy layer style` from the first layer and then `Paste layer style` on all the destination layers at once).

If layers were flattened (which doesn't seem to be your case), you'd do the same, but once you choose the color you should change `Blend Mode` to `Color`

Answer (score 0):

Not really the cleanest approach, but the easiest way I see to do it is this:

1. When you are done making all transformations, duplicate all layers,
   and merge them into a single layer. (Select All Layers, Cmd-J,
   followed by Cmd-E)
2. Under "**Select**", select by **color range**, and click on a White
   portion on your image. Adjust the threshold to only cover the white
   portion while ignoring the "text" regions.
3. Inverse your selection.
4. Cmd-J to duplicate this. This will give you just the Text component in a new layer.
5. While being on this new layer, Cmd-Click on the new layer thumbnail to select this portion again,
   and Fill it
       (Shift+f5) with a color.
6. Adjust the Blend Mode to Overlay, adjust the opacity/fill to get the
   desired saturation.

Answer (score 0):

I see your text layers are in fact rasterised (not editable type) and have a transparent background. Here's a simple method to colourise them.

1. Choose a new foreground colour.
2. Select the layer you want to colourise.
3. Engage the Transparent Pixel Lock (shown circled in red below)
4. Edit > Fill > choose the Foreground colour.

[image]

Comment: omg i finally figured out due to your help!!! thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!you are genius!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If possible, try to avoid changing pixels to change the color and use filtering and masking instead.

First a simple solution, which only works if all your text layers has transparency (which it seems like yours have).

- In the `Layers Panel`, select all layers containing the text/objects you want to color. They all have to have transparency - no background.
- `SHIFT-CLICK` the `Group` icon to group the selected layers.
- Create a `Solid Color` Layer on top of the `Group`.
- `ALT-CLICK` between the `Solid Color` layer and the `Group`. This "indents" the `Solid Color` layer meaning it only affects the `Group` below.

[image: Solid Color layer]

This colors everything inside the group according to its transparency. You can always double-click the Solid Color layer's "color swatch" and select another color.

If you want to control both text and background color you could do this:

- Press `CTRL+A / CMD+A` to select all.
- Press `SHIFT+CTRL+C / SHIFT+CMD+C` or choose `Edit/Copy Merged` to make a merged copy of the document.
- Create two new `Solid Color` layers - one for the background and one for the letters.
- `ALT+CLICK` the mask of the letter (topmost) `Solid Color` layer to enter "mask mode".
- Press `CTRL+V` to paste in the merged image.
- Press `CTRL+D` to deselect all (important).
- Press `CTRL+I` to invert the mask.
- Click the "color swatch" of the `Solid Color` layer to return to "normal mode".

[image: Two Solid Color layers]

This is a nice setup, because you can easily change he two colors without changing the shape of the letters and with no leftover trace from previous coloring.

The downside is of course, that your artwork now is flattened inside the mask. You can enter the mask and adjust it, or make your changes in the original layers and repeat the process.

Comment: thank u so much for your kind answer! can i ask one more question? when i was following your instructions, when i selected the solid color color layer and set the blend mode to color, only the outline color of typeface changed. what do you think the problem is? :( (my  typeface looks like the color i  chose and black is blended...not like yours)

Comment: You're welcome. But I'm sorry - I believe the first solution isn't very useful. It seems the "Color" blend mode doesn't work the way we want when the underlying color gets too dark (more than 70-80% grey). It worked on the screenshot you posted. I will delete that first part, but add another simple solution. It only works if all your layers have transparency though.